# Why is the time to use RubyGems with the LoadError?

Tags: linux, fedora, ruby, gem

My PC (Gnu/Linux Fedora 30) was running a crawling program that was turned off because of the power outage, After that, my crawler and any other Ruby Gem did not work,and displays the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
8: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
7: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
6: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
5: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1365:in `<module:Gem>'
4: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1365:in `require'
3: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:16:in `require'
1: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- delegate (LoadError)
```

or

```
$ gem env version
 Traceback (most recent call last):
8: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
7: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
6: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
5: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1365:in `<module:Gem>'
4: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1365:in `require'
3: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:16:in `require'
1: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- delegate (LoadError)
```

and When I want to see Gem version :

```
$ gem -v
 Traceback (most recent call last):
8: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
7: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
6: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
5: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1365:in `<module:Gem>'
4: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1365:in `require'
3: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:16:in `require'
1: from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- delegate (LoadError)
```

my ruby version :

```
$ ruby -v
 ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
```

After reinstalling Ruby, nothing changed.

Comment: What operating system / distro? Can you try simply reinstalling Ruby?

Comment: Fedora 30, After reinstalling Ruby nothing changed